# li jquery on click: if to switch

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement, switch-statement

I'm making a simple filter system where each li value has a certain description.
Currently it's working with an IF statement, but I'd like to convert it to a switch. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

My code:

```
$("ul.simplefilter").on('click', 'li', function (e) {

if($(this).text() == "Iedereen"){
    $("#uitleg p").remove();
    $("#uitleg").append("<p>Iedereen</p>");        
}
else if($(this).text() == "Coach studentenparticipatie"){ 
    $("#uitleg p").remove();    
    $("#uitleg").append("<p>Coach studentenparticipatie</p>");
}
else if($(this).text() == "Communicatie"){ 
    $("#uitleg p").remove();    
    $("#uitleg").append("<p>Communicatie</p>");
}
else if($(this).text() == "Coördinator"){ 
    $("#uitleg p").remove();    
    $("#uitleg").append("<p>Coördinator</p>");
}
})
```

Comment: `switch($(this).text)` and match cases `case "Iedereen" : ` etc

Comment: Assuming things. Try: `$('#uitleg').html('<p>' + $(this).text() + '</p>');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this possible?

Yes, just use `switch` statement.

```
$("ul.simplefilter").on('click', 'li', function (e) {
   switch($(this).text()){
     case "Iedereen":
        $("#uitleg p").remove();
        $("#uitleg").append("<p>Iedereen</p>");
        break;
     case "Coach studentenparticipatie":
        $("#uitleg p").remove();    
        $("#uitleg").append("<p>Coach studentenparticipatie</p>");
        break;

   }
});
```

Also, you can achieve that with single line using `.html()` method.

```
$("ul.simplefilter").on('click', 'li', function (e) {
     $('#uitleg').html('<p>'+$(this).text()+'</p>');
});
```

If you have, for instance, 100 values it is expensive to write 100 cases, just use `.html()` method.

Answer (score 0):

The switch statement will look something like this:

```
$("ul.simplefilter").on('click', 'li', function (e) {

switch($(this).text()){
    case "Iedereen" :
      $("#uitleg p").remove();
      $("#uitleg").append("<p>Iedereen</p>");
      break;
....
```

PS. Don't forget the `break;` on each case.